# Cual es la forma correcta para poder realizar una consulta sql?

Tags: sql, django, api

Estoy desarrollando un API - REST con Django, aun soy muy nuevo en esto.
no me agrada el ORM, el desconocimiento hace realmente que tenga limitaciones con la consultas.
Me pregunto cual es la forma correcta realizar una consulta SQL ya que de la forma que lo hago tengo entendido que pueden inyectar código SQL en mi API.
Yo lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```
def loteExistente(self,lote):
try:
    cursor = Zetone.cursor()
    sqlQuery = ("SELECT Lote\n" +
                "FROM MovimientosBins\n" +
                "WHERE Lote='" + lote + "'")
    cursor.execute(sqlQuery)
    paquete = cursor.fetchall()
    if paquete:
        respuesta = 'Success'
        dc= [{'Info':respuesta}]
        txt = [dc]
        return HttpResponse(txt)
    else:
        cursor.close()
        respuesta = 'Fail'
        dc= [{'Info':respuesta}]
        txt = [dc]
        return HttpResponse(txt)
    
except Exception as e:
    print (e)


def Prueba(self,camara):
try:
    cursor = Z.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT MovimientosBins.Lote, MovimientosBins.Camara, MovimientosBins.Total, MovimientosBins.Parcial, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MovimientosBins.Fecha, 103), \n" + 
    "MovimientosBins.Legajo, MovimientosBins.Estado, Serenos.sereno \n" +
    "FROM MovimientosBins INNER JOIN \n" +
    "Serenos ON MovimientosBins.Legajo = Serenos.id\n" + 
    "WHERE Camara='" + camara + "'")
    paquete = cursor.fetchall()
    if paquete:
        dc = []
        j = 0
        mov = cursor.fetchall()
        for mov in paquete:            
            pb = {'ID':j,'Lote':mov[0], 'Camara':mov[1], 'Total':mov[2], 'Parcial':mov[3], 'Fecha':mov[4],'Hora':mov[5], 'Legajo':mov[7]}
            dc.append(pb)
            j = j+1
        js = json.dumps(dc, indent=None, sort_keys=False)
        return HttpResponse(js)
    else:
        txt = 'None'
        dc={'Info': txt}
        #js = json.dumps(dc, indent=None, sort_keys=False)
        return JsonResponse(dc)
except:
    print("EXCEPT2")
  
def envioLote(self,lote,camara,total,parcial,fecha,hora,legajo,estado):
records = [lote,camara,total,parcial,fecha,hora,legajo,estado]
try:
    cursor = Z.cursor()
    sqlQuery = ("INSERT INTO MovimientosBins (Lote, Camara, Total, Parcial, Fecha, Hora, Legajo, Estado)\n" +
    " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)")
    cursor.execute(sqlQuery,records)
    cursor.commit()
    cursor.close()
    respuesta = 'Success'
    dc= [{'Info':respuesta}]
    txt = [dc]
    return HttpResponse(txt)
    
except Exception as e:
  print (e)
```

Agradezco mucho su ayuda y gracias por compartir el conocimiento